# Sync direction not working as expected

Tags: c#, microsoft-sync-framework

I have a project that uses Microsoft Sync Framework. Everything is working fine except the Sync direction. I set the Sync direction of the Synch Orchestrator depending on the user's choice if it will be Upload or Download.

Edit:

I have uploaded a document to better explain the situation:

[google doc link](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BzNIZTJXVnAWbVZSWU5mNEx3eFk/edit?usp=sharing)

Code:

```
private void RunSynch()
{
    SqlConnection sqlServer = new SqlConnection(GetServerConnectionString());
    SqlConnection sqlClient = new SqlConnection(GetClientConnectionString());

    SyncOrchestrator syncOrchestrator = new SyncOrchestrator();
    syncOrchestrator.LocalProvider = new SqlSyncProvider(strScopeName, sqlClient);
    syncOrchestrator.RemoteProvider = new SqlSyncProvider(strScopeName, sqlServer); 

    switch(iButtonState) // int constant
    {
        case STATE_UPLOAD:

            syncOrchestrator.Direction = SyncDirectionOrder.Upload;
            break;

        case STATE_DOWNLOAD:

            syncOrchestrator.Direction = SyncDirectionOrder.Download;
            break;
    }

    ((SqlSyncProvider)syncOrchestrator.RemoteProvider).ApplyChangeFailed += new EventHandler<DbApplyChangeFailedEventArgs>(RemoteProvider_ApplyChangeFailed);
    ((SqlSyncProvider)syncOrchestrator.LocalProvider).ApplyChangeFailed += new EventHandler<DbApplyChangeFailedEventArgs>(LocalProvider_ApplyChangeFailed);

    syncStats = syncOrchestrator.Synchronize();
}



private void RemoteProvider_ApplyChangeFailed(object sender, DbApplyChangeFailedEventArgs e)
{

    if (rdoConflict.SelectedIndex == 0)// server wins option
    {
        e.Action = ApplyAction.Continue;
    }
    else
    {
        e.Action = ApplyAction.RetryWithForceWrite;
    }
}

private void LocalProvider_ApplyChangeFailed(object sender, DbApplyChangeFailedEventArgs e)
{
    if (rdoConflict.SelectedIndex == 0) // server wins option
    {
        e.Action = ApplyAction.RetryWithForceWrite;
    }
    else
    {
        e.Action = ApplyAction.Continue;
    }
}
```

The problem here is the server database gets updated by the clients changes even if the synch direction is only Download.

Fixed:

I got it finally working now. There was totally no issue with the synch framework but its the switch part where the Direction is assigned, I debugged and found out that the program doesnt go through the switch case thats why the direction is always bi-directional.

Comment: Please provide us some piece of code what you have implemented

Comment: in a download scenario, the client never sends data to the server. can you do a simple test, subscribe to the local provider's ChangesSelected event and see if it actually fires in your download scenario (it should not)

Comment: I got finally working now. There was totally no issue with the synch framework but its the switch part where the Direction is assigned, I debugged and found out that the program doesnt go through the switch case thats why the direction is always bi-directional. This is really embarassing. Sorry guys and thanks for all the help! I totally spaced out on this one :")

Answer (score 1):

I got the reason finally:

What is happening the first time you sync the databases.

If both of them have different data then all Rows will be conflicted.

And in case of conflict Server Wins always by default (You can change it to Remote Wins) also

So all the changes come to the remote and thats whay you wonder that Sync Framework is wrong.

REASON:

Later when some conflicts occur by changing remote and central db same time the server wins

UPDATE:

With your providers use this:

```
localProvider.ApplyChangeFailed += new EventHandler<DbApplyChangeFailedEventArgs>(LocalProvider_ApplyChangeFailed);
remoteProvider.ApplyChangeFailed += new EventHandler<DbApplyChangeFailedEventArgs>(RemoteProvider_ApplyChangeFailed);


private void LocalProvider_ApplyChangeFailed(object sender, DbApplyChangeFailedEventArgs e)
    {


     // Need to right your conditions like 
        e.Action = ApplyAction.Continue;

    }
```

Comment: the default behaviour for a conflict is ApplyAction.Continue which basically means ignore the conflict and dont apply the change. in an upload scenario, this meas the destination or remote will not be change. in a download, it means keep the local copy.

Comment: Do conflicts only happen when changes are made to both sources? When I sync records to a client and then changes are made on the client's records and then I synch (Download Direction) and no records are changed on the server, the records on the server gets updated by the records from the client. Should this really happen? I thought Download direction will only apply changes from the Server, but it seems to apply changes from the client to the server.

Comment: When the records are changed on both sides the conflicts always occur and you need to handle it.and FYI dont use int ID as primary key preferably use GUID etc. This is one of the necessity of Synchronization

Comment: What if the data is only changed on one side, client for example, and then I Download from the server with no changes. My records from the server gets updated

Comment: See if seems confusing-- When you insert new records after once sync there is no conflict but if the same record exist on both side found by Primary key is changed then there is a conflict. Fo new Inserts the Sync Framework works correctly

Comment: How does the CollisionConflictResolutionPolicy of the providers affect the ApplyChangesFailed?

Comment: I didnt know that CollisionConflictResolutionPolicy is not affecting the conflicts for relational providers until I read @JuneT comment in this post:
http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-PH/syncdevdiscussions/thread/cbf908af-1b6d-4285-b6dd-192c7a312ce0

Comment: @Gian - in a Download only scenario, the records from the source will never be updated with the ones  from destination. you might want to post your code snippets so we can have a look if something's amiss.

Comment: @Gian - conflicts dont just occur for updates. it could happen to inserts as well.e.g., you insert row id 1 in local and another row with id  1 is also inserted in server. conflicts can occur on updates in local and deletes on remote or vice versa, etc...

Comment: @JuneT I have edited the question and included a document